# Java 8 stream optimization for nested level

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can we use optimize this stream to collect nested level and root level for a set.

```
final Set<String> groupedUsers = new HashSet<>();
groups.stream().forEach(group -> {
    groupedUsers.add(group.getTeamLeadId());
    groupedUsers.addAll(group.getTeamMemberIds().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
});
```

Comment: IMHO, you should define *optimize this stream* primarily to make the question clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `forEach` to add elements to a collection.

```
Set<String> groupedUsers = groups.stream()
    .flatMap(g -> Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(g.getTeamLeadId()), g.getTeamMemberIds().stream()))
    .collect(toSet());
```

Or just use a plain old (enhanced) for loop. Streams don't give you any clear advantage here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Stream API` and `lambdas` don't give you any advantage here.

> optimize this stream to collect

If I get correctly the meaning of your **"optimize"** word, then I would go with old-style `foreach`:

```
Set<String> groupedUsers = new HashSet<>();
for (Group g : groups) {
    groupedUsers.add(g.getTeamLeadId());
    groupedUsers.addAll(g.getTeamMemberIds());
}
```

> If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: Isn't that same as the other answers existing here? Or does this have any performance advantage (if you meant that) over them?

Comment: @nullpointer Nope, it isn't. It doesn't have any overhead related to streams and lambdas. I believe this is not the case situation to use `Stream API`.

Comment: By other answers, I meant for example [the answer by Karol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850182/1746118) doesn't use streams either. I was asking a comparison of your code's performance with theirs.

Comment: @ETO and *lambdas are not streams* if that's where we were diving by any chance in this discussion.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Yes, I know. But  by using a lambda in this particular case you do not optimize anything.

Comment: Okay. I missed that one in the comment and couldn't find it in the answer. Maybe it would be good to mention both in the answer then as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip stream creation in `groups.stream().forEach()` because of [`Iterable.forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-)

```
groups.forEach(group -> {
  ..
});
```

Streams are generally more costly than regular iteration due to years of loop optimization put into JIT.

Comment: how does this answers the question?

Comment: @Eugene Streams are more costly than regular iteration. It's hard to tell what is meant by "optimize the stream". Stream with `flatMap` will be more readable but regular `for` loop will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Or may be even:

```
    Set<String> groupedUsers = new HashSet<>();
    groups.forEach(x -> {
        groupedUsers.add(x.getTeamLeadId());
        groupedUsers.addAll(x.getTeamMemberIds());
    });
```

Comment: I think you ended up answering same as Karol. If I am not misunderstanding the intention there.